# Tool Tip is fixed at a position

Tags: css, tooltip

I am displaying a ToolTip on  a chart currently .

The issue is that the tooltip is postioned at one place only (Means where everever the Mouse is placed on the chart , the tool tip is shown at a specific position only )

Is it possible to move the tooltip where the mouse is positioned at

```
This is my css 

.flotr-mouse-value {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight:bold;
 }

var mt = this.mouseTrack || this.el.select(".flotr-mouse-value")[0],
  elStyle = 'background: yellow;height: 75px;-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666; -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;position: absolute;box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #666;left: 50px;top: 50px;width: 150px;height: 80px;';
```

please help , thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo cant do this with just CSS. The easiest way would be with jQuery, using something like this:http://www.queness.com/post/92/create-a-simple-cssjavascript-tooltip-with-jquery

Comment: I am using Prototype.js , so any other ideas??

Comment: try this page, many tootip demo's. I googled it. http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/prototip/

Comment: Thank you very much , This was solved using mouse: {track: true,relative:true , specific to FLotr API .